# Mspdebug Can't receive data

Tags: linux, ubuntu, microcontroller, ubuntu-12.04, msp430

I am trying to learn to program microcontrollers. I am starting with the msp430 and I have installed mspdebug 0.18 and mspgcc 4.5.3. I would like to load a simple program onto the device for testing, but mspdebug cannot get pass erasing the device.

```
Device: MSP-EXP430FR5739  
Computer OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS  

Error Messages:  
Trying to program device:  
(mspdebug) prog led.elf  
Erasing...  
rf2500: can't receive data: Resource temporarily unavailable  
fet: erase command failed  

Trying solely to erase device
(mspdebug) erase  
Erasing...  
rf2500: can't receive data: Resource temporarily unavailable  
fet: erase command failed  

Output of dmesg after unplugging and plugging in the device:  
[ 1537.370302] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 3  
[ 1544.276180] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ohci_hcd  
[ 1544.476821] cdc_acm 3-2:1.0: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.  
[ 1544.476838] cdc_acm 3-2:1.0: No union descriptor, testing for castrated device  
[ 1544.476903] cdc_acm 3-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

Comment: If you're not using GCC for a specific reason, I wouldn't recommend starting with it - I've found support a bit sparse. I would recommend the proprietary CCS compiler from TI or the Embedded Workbench from IAR Systems (both have free versions). Both should be far easier to get *something* up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with erasing not working (or at least not working as usual) on the FRAM chips. You should update to the latest version of mspdebug ( http://mspdebug.sourceforge.net/ ) which takes care of that.